# How can make a file `VERSION` contains version number every time the repository is exported?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a file called VERSION in the repository root. Everytime I deploy the repository I put the output of `svnversion` in that file manually. But I want that my VCS manages it. So every time I `export` the whole repository or just the VERSION file it should contain 2 things at least.

1. Version/Revision number of the whole repository
2. Last modified date of the whole repository.

Currently I do this by

```
svn info | tail -4 | cut -f3- -d" " > VERSION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subwcrev template-file (may be outside repo) into VERSION file inside exported tree.

2 commands, but without handwork